# Python. При срабатывании метода не рисуется таблица из PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Скажите пожалуйста, почему при срабатывании условия в методе класса - не строится таблица.

При нажатии на плитку `first point` подается сигнал на метод `type change`, тот в свою очередь должен построить таблицу. Но этого не происходит. Пожалуйста, выручайте.

код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QComboBox, QTableWidget


class gen_window(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        show_type_window = QComboBox(self)  # комбо-бокс с двумя плитками
        show_type_window.addItem('first point')
        show_type_window.addItem('second point')
        show_type_window.move(10, 47)

        show_type_window.activated['int'].connect(self.type_change)  # проверка, отсылающая индекс выбранной плитки в 'type_change'

        self.resize(900, 650)  # size of general window
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.show()

    def type_change(self, index):
        if index == 0:  # если индекс нажатой плитки равен 0, то построить таблицу.
            table = QTableWidget(self)
            table.setColumnCount(8)
            table.setRowCount(20)
            table.move(10, 90)
            table.resize(880, 550)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = gen_window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:** Ребята, с ответом мне очень помог парень @S.Nick, оказывается, что нужно было в конце метода type_change поставить `table.show`!

Comment: в конце метола `type_change` добавьте строку `table.show()`

Comment: О боже, дружище, спасибо тебе! Чёрт возьми я сейчас блин заплачу! Всё заработало, спасибо тебе еще раз!

Comment: Пожалуйста, бывает.